# A Living Trust, and Individual account and SPIC

Tags: united-states, brokerage

Please consider an investor who has 400K in stocks in an individual account at a brokerage firm. He also has a living revocable trust which also has an account at the same brokerage firm. The value of the living revocable trust is 300K.

There is no TOD (transfer on death) on the individual account and the person's will leaves everything to the living trust.

Will both accounts be fully covered by SIPC? That is, will both accounts have a separate 500K limit on the SPIC coverage or will SIPC consider both accounts to be the same account and apply the 500K limit to both accounts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both FDIC and SIPC insure all the customers' covered assets in the institution, up to their limits. It doesn't matter how many accounts the customer has ([source](https://www.sipc.org/for-investors/investor-faqs#i-have-two-accounts-a-margin-account-and-a-non-margin-cash-account.is-each-account-protected-separately)) and how their assets are split between the accounts.

Note that a trust account is covered separately from the investor's individual account ([rule 104](https://www.sipc.org/about-sipc/statute-and-rules/series100)), so until death they're owned by *different* legal entities and are covered separately.

But after the will is executed and the individual account is transferred to the trust, the values will be combined even if the accounts remain separate. So by having $700K in the investment portfolio stored at that brokerage, the trust would be $200K above the SIPC limit.

Comment: The link you mentioned says: (a) A trust account held with a member shall be deemed a “qualifying trust account” if it is held on behalf of a valid and subsisting express trust created by a written instrument. No account held on behalf of a trust that on the filing date existed primarily to obtain or increase protection under the Act shall be deemed to be a qualifying trust account.                                                                        In this context what does the filing date mean?

Comment: @Bob Date of filing a claim with SIPC. Basically it means that creating trusts *just* so that you can have multiple legal entities insured is not going to fly. But if you have a true and legitimate trust - then it is a separate legal entity, and will be insured separately.